# Unable to change UITableViewController color background

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, background

TitlesViewController : UITableViewController

I have the above code on iPhone development.  This is associated to a xib (or nib) file.  In this property file I change its background color.  The problem is it does not reflect my new background color.  Should I be manually loading the xib file to reflect it to my TitlesViewController?

Comment: What do you mean when you say, "This is associated to a xib (or nib) file"? Are you actually loading the nib somewhere? It doesn't do any good simply existing, and setting File's Owner won't actually change anything.

Answer (score 0):

viewcontroller.view.backgroundColor=color;

Comment: Well I was trying to change my tables background color through its nib file.  I don't wanna do it programmatically.  However I became desperate and did it programmatically.  I have an issue on that.. see my new question.

Answer (score 0):

Some quick points:

You don't change the colour of a view controller, you change the colour of a view controller's view.

A xib is an XML file that tells Xcode how to create a matching nib. Neither are property files (you are likely mixing them up with plist files).

You should be able to set the background colour for just about any UIView (or subclass thereof) in your xib file. So the question is, how were you setting it the colour, what were you expecting to happen, and what did you get?